# Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [name] in table [testTable]

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

i'm getting this error while starting my springboot application:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [name] in table [testTable];
found [character (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [clob (Types#CLOB)]
```

Other people of my team can run it just fine, but it doesn't work for me.

This is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testTable")
data class TestTable(

    @Id
    val id: Long,

    @Lob
    @Column
    val name: String,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val parentId: Long,
```

I guess its a problem with mapping, but I don't understand why other people don't have the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add information about DB you are using and jdbc driver version

Answer (score 0):

Other people of your team probably use a different database schema. The error says that your model requires a `CLOB` column type (due to the use of `@Lob`), but the database column has the type `VARCHAR`. If you want to work with this schema, remove the `@Lob` annotation. Otherwise, migrate the column to CLOB: `alter table testTable alter column name set data type clob`